# Should password reset pages automatically authenticate users?

Tags: passwords, usability, security, password-protection

Many lost password workflows usually result in a page which is reached by a temporary link emailed to the user. This link then takes them to a page that asks for a new password.

Upon entering the new password should a user be forced to logon manually, or should the password reset page authenticate the user automatically which would reduce the number of steps and thus complexity of the process for the end user?

I often encounter password reset pages that make me reset my password and then login which feels like I'm logging in twice for no good reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any significant advantage to forcing the user to re-enter the password that they just entered twice. If someone does, I'd be interested to hear about it.

Comment: Not a significant advantage, but forcing a manual login immediately after password reset could help in updating their browser's saved password to the new one. Non-technical users would become confused if they reset their password and when they return next week the saved password no longer works.

Comment: That's a good point, and one that I hadn't considered. Arguably, there may be other ways to do this, such as by ensuring that the password-setting form looks enough like the password-entry form to trigger the browser's password-saving code.

Comment: Plus, it gets them to start associating the look of the login page with their new password immediately rather than after X amount of time, making it easier to remember it.

Answer (score 4):

I quite like drupal's method: The user gets sent an email with a link in it which will log them on once; upon logging in with it they are given the opportunity to change their password.

Comment: That's *almost* the right way to go. Better to give them a link that will let them set the password, but will not let them log on.

Answer (score 1):

You should make it auto login. Don't see why you would make the user login.

If it's because of bot protection, just add a captcha when the user logins using the link.

Comment: I don't even see how it would offer bot protection, since the whole point is that the link was only made available to the recipient at that email address.